# Upgrade TinyMCE to 5, one form does not show the editor on a textarea control

Tags: tinymce-5

I'm using Bootstrap 4.5, and have several forms all using the exact same setup to call TinyMCE 5, but one form (the most complex of course) is not showing it. I can find nothing wrong, or anything different between the way the textarea control is created. The code to load TinyMCE is being loaded in a PHP program and is therefore identical in all cases. This is the code being streamed out:

```
  <!-- Jquery -- required for interactive parts of bootstrap and other code to function -->
  <script src="../../Awards/jscode/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript, popper.js required for tooltips and such -->
  <script src="../../Awards/jscode/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Awards/jscode/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- TinyMCE -->
  <script src="../../Awards/jscode/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  
  <script language="JavaScript">
     // TinyMCE, set for all textarea controls, with specific toolbar items, no menubar, etc.:
     tinymce.init(
     {
        selector: 'textarea',
        menubar: false,
        branding: false,
        plugins: 'code lists',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent | code',
        lists_indent_on_tab: true,
        content_css: '<?php echo $Award_html_RootPath; ?>css/AwardList.css'
     }); // end of TinyMCE code
  </script>
```

This works for other forms with the same code being streamed out for each. I am stumped as to why this one form doesn't display TinyMCE. The textarea control in question is:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <textarea name="Notes" id="Notes"
               class="form-control"
               style="height: 250px;"></textarea>
</div> <!-- / form-group -->
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions that might point me to where the problem lies. There is a lot of JavaScript for this form but it all seems to work, it's just the TinyMCE code that doesn't want to load ... it displays as a standard textarea, no overlay for TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so now I feel really sheepish. I was outputting at the top of the page some styles before the header information was loaded properly, so TinyMCE wasn't seeing "standards" mode, which includes the first line of the HTML file needing to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Moved the script tags to below the code that streams the header into the page so that, among other things, the doctype tag above is the first line, and all is well. Sorry for wasting anyone's time on this.